# Como saber si el índice de un arreglo es primo

Tags: java

Tengo un arreglo booleano inicializado en true, tengo que recorrer ese arreglo y el índice del arreglo que no sea primo cambiar el valor del arreglo en ese índice a false. Esta es la parte del código en la que tengo duda

```
  int contador = 2;

  for(int i = 2; i < numeros.length; i++){
      while((numeros[i]) && ( contador != numero)){
         if(numero%contador==0)
              numeros[i] = false;
         j++;
    }
  }
```

**Lo que me pasa es que cuando imprimo el arreglo no tiene los valores booleanos modificados, todos se muestran en true**

Comment: Pista: ¿Cuál es el valor inicial de *numeros[i]*?

Comment: true, el arreglo numeros está inicializado en true y estoy comenzando a partir de la posición 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `i` contiene el índice del arreglo.

Por cada índice se comprobará si es primo dividiéndolo entre todos los números entre 2 y la raíz cuadrada de `i`, si es divisible por alguno, el elemento en la posición `i` será falso.

```
for (int i = 3; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    boolean primo = true;
    for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++)
        if (i % j == 0) {
            primo = false;
            break;
        }
    numeros[i] = false;
}
```